# Is it possible to assign a button a dynamic variable; that changes for each row fetched from the query in a while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have a `query` that produces a table using a `while loop` for each row it finds. However my goal is to have each `row` with an add button that when pressed takes two variables and `INSERTS` a new row in another table. I believe the reason my code isn't working to be down to the system not being able to identify which add button belongs to which row. I have tried assigning the UserID of each row to the `button id` but it still fails to `INSERT`. (It produces no errors).

Any suggests as to how I can achieve my goal?

**HTML + PHP:**

```
<div class="RightBody">
  <form name="search_form" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" placeholder="Search for skills or a user." />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >
        <p><strong>Search Results:</strong></p>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Job Role</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Skill(s)</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
      if(@mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0){
          do{ 
            if(isset($_POST['adduser'])){
              $AddUserID = $search_rs['UserID'];
              $AddProjectID = $Project;

              $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO userprojects (UserID, ProjectID) VALUES  ('$AddUserID', '$AddProjectID')") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
            }?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="submit" name="adduser" value="Add"  id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($search_rs['UserID']); ?>"/>
              </td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['Fname']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['Lname']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['JobRole']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['Description']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php   
          } 
          while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
      } 
      else 
      {
        echo "No results found";
      }
    }?>
        </table>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$value = isset($_POST['search_box']) ? $_POST['search_box'] : '';

$search_sql = "SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN UserSkills ON User.UserId = UserSkills.UserId JOIN Skills ON UserSkills.SkillId = Skills.SkillId WHERE Description LIKE '%".$value."%' OR FName LIKE '%".$value."%' OR LName LIKE '%".$value."%' OR JobRole LIKE '%".$value."%' GROUP BY Description" or die(mysqli_error($con));

$search_query = mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
  $search_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
```

Comment: Might be just me, but... given the code you've posted I have no idea how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Well my code doesn't have to stay the way it is. I just need to achieve my goal mentioned above. If you know of a better way to go about it I'm happy to try it :)

Comment: for this `<td>
                <input type="submit" name="adduser" value="Add"  id="<?php htmlspecialchars($search_rs['UserID']); ?>"/>
              </td>` where is your `<form></form>` ??

Comment: Without `<form></form>` how you can't submit any value ?? And, this is not the way.

Comment: In your `<form>`, you need to specify the `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `action` attribute in your `<form>`.

Also, `htmlspecialchars(value)` [will *return* a string, not output it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), so instead of using:

```
<?php htmlspecialchars($search_rs['UserID']);
```

you need to use

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($search_rs['UserID']);
```

Comment: I have added echo to `htmlspecialchars(value)`.

Comment: I cannot tell if your suggested change works because I cannot get the code to work. RamRaider suggested using Ajax but I have never used it before so I'm finding it incredibly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `submit` button I'd change it to a standard button and supply each button with the variables you mention as data-values.

```
/* in the php loop */
<input type='button' class='dynbttn' data-uid='{$AddUserID}' data-pid='{$AddProjectID}' value='Add User' />

/* javascript listeners */
var col=document.querySelectorAll('input.dynbttn');
for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].onclick=function(e){
    var el=typeof(e.target)!='undefined' ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    var uid=el.dataset.uid;
    var pid=el.dataset.pid;
    alert( 'Use ajax to submit the values:'+uid+','+pid );
};
```

example:

```
<script>
    function ajax(m,u,p,c){
        /*
            m=method
            u=url
            p=params {name:value}
            c=callback
        */
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call(this,xhr.response);
        };

        var params=[];
        for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

        switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
            case 'post':
                p=params;
            break;
            case 'get':
                u+='?'+params;
                p=null;
            break;  
        }

        xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send( p );
    }

    function callback(r){
        alert(r);
    }

    function bindEvents(){
        var col=document.querySelectorAll('input.dynbttn');
        for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].onclick=function(e){
            var el=typeof(e.target)!='undefined' ? e.target : e.srcElement;
            var uid=el.dataset.uid;
            var pid=el.dataset.pid;

            ajax.call( this, 'post', '/path/to/script.php', { uid:uid,pid:pid }, callback );
        };
    }   
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded',bindEvents,false );
</script>
```

Comment: Where should I put the javascript listeners? Inside or outside the php loop?

Comment: Not in the loop. Either in the head part of the document ( using a suitable onload event handler ) or at the end of the document, after the loop.

Comment: I am struggling to find out how to submit the values using ajax. Do you have any examples that might aid me, or previous stack questions?

Comment: Thank you for adding that example, however as I have not encountered ajax before, your example is mega confusing to me. Not sure what any of it does :(